# Micronaut + GraalVM + M1 - Creating a docker image with dockerBuildNative generates for amd64 instead of arm64

Tags: docker, apple-m1, arm64, micronaut, graalvm-native-image

I'm using Micronaut 4.0.3 and I managed to create a GraalVM native executable docker image with the following command:

```
./gradlew dockerBuildNative
```

The resulting image is for `linux/amd64`. I can see this in dockerhub when pushing it, and also if I run:

```
docker image inspect <image-name>:latest
```

The output contains this line `"Architecture": "amd64"`
When I try to run this docker container it obviously doesn't work on my local machine (MacOS, M1).
I tried adding this to my `build.gradle` file, but without success:

```
dockerfileNative {
    graalArch.set("aarch64")
}
```

I have 2 questions here:

1. How can I make the dockerBuildNative generate an arm64 image?
2. How can I pass a tag so that the docker image is built with it? As a workaround I know I can use `docker tag` to change it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was the resulting image was based on `frolvlad/alpine-glibc`, which doesn't have a linux/arm64 version.
To fix this, I added this in `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.named("dockerfileNative") {
    baseImage('ubuntu:latest')
}
```